# How do I go about muting a specific audio source in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to mute a specific audio source once my death menu pops up ingame. I tried with:

```
  public void toggleEndMenu(float score)
    {
        GameObject jumpGameObject = GameObject.Find("Jump");
        if (jumpGameObject != null)
        {
            AudioSource jumpAudio = jumpGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            if (jumpAudio != null)
            {
                jumpAudio.mute = true;
            }
        }

        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        scoreText.text = ((int)score).ToString();
        isShown = true;
```

This did not work the audiosource does not get muted, maybe it cannot find the gameobject or something?

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Is `jumpGameObject` or `jumpAudio` null? Also, GameObject.Find: "Finds a GameObject by name and returns it. This function only returns active GameObjects." Is the GO active?

Comment: The gameobject is active, How can i check if jumpGameObject or jumpAudio is null with the debugger? Sorry I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: Type `Debug.Log(jumpGameObject)` in code and look at console output. Or if you have Visual Studio you can use breakpoints.

Comment: I used that line of code and it did output: Jump(Unity.Engine.GameObject) Unity.Engime:debug:Log(Object)      in the console